# Use alarm volume level for exoPlayer in android

Tags: android, volume, exoplayer

I use `ExoPlayer` for my alarm clock app and I want it to playback music using alarm volume instead of music volume (which is default). When it starts to playback, volume should be increased gradually from mute to the current alarm volume level.

I can totally get both current and maximum volume levels but I can't find any methods in `ExoPlayer` to use them. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31517573/adjust-dash-stream-volume-with-android-exoplayer), but it seems that for ExoPlayer v2.0.4 it doesn't work. Any ideas will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In version 2.4+ you can use

```
player.setAudioStreamType(C.STREAM_TYPE_ALARM);
```